# Packing L's in Tans and L's in L's

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, packing-and-covering

I'm  a young researcher and I'm pretty new in this field. I want to work on packing problem "L's in Tans" and "L's in L's" as presented on https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing . On link can be found some known optimal packings, but I can't find any papers related to this problem.

Can someone show me some papers related to this problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Too many questions at once. Please be more specific. What is the connection of genetic algorithms and the link?

Comment: @DieterKadelka I edited question, hope now is more specific.

Comment: The packing center is now located at https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be hard to find literature on the specific families of packing problems you mentioned. However, they are special cases of a more general pattern of asking for the optimal packing of $N$ congruent copies of an object inside another object. You can find many papers tackling this type of problem, see what kind of computational methods they use, and try to apply them to your problems. For example, [here](https://www.pnas.org/content/113/6/E669.full) is a paper studying the problem of packing Platonic solids into a sphere using a simulated-annealing-like Monte Carlo approach.